# Looking for specific regex

Tags: c#, regex

I've been looking to create a regex for my specific situation. The furthest i've come with my own limited knowledge of Regex and by searching on StackOverflow is this Regex:

```
^[pP][a-zA-Z0-9- ]*
```

I'm looking for a Regex which forces the string to:

- start with the letter 'p' or 'P', so lower and uppercase
- is not shorter than 19 characters long
- may contain '-', '%20', ' ' or '+'
- end with '0000'
- be alphanumeric inbetween the 'p' and the four zero's and the '-', '%20', ' ' or '+' delimiters

Examples of strings that should match the Regex:

- PLX000000000PQ50000
- pLX000000000PQ50000
- plx000000000pq50000
- PLX-0000-0000-0PQ5-0000
- PLX-0000-0000-0PQ50000
- PLX+0000+0000+0PQ5+0000
- PLX%200000%200000%200PQ5%200000
- PLX 0000 0000 0PQ5 0000

What is the Regex I'm looking for?
The language I'm using is C#

Comment: Do you want to reject all `%` not followed by 20?

Comment: Yes I only want the complete string of "%20" to be matched if it's found in the string

Comment: I have seldomly seen such a good description for the regex requirements! have an upvote (I'd give 2 if I could)

Comment: Should %20 count as a single or triple char?

Comment: @FrancescoB. I don't completely understand your question. But I want the Regex to match only if the characters '%', '2' and '0' are present consecutively.

Comment: Let me use an example: the following string *plx%20d0000pq50000* is 18 character long, but if you count *%20* not as 3 characters but just 1 (since it is the url encoding of a white space), the string can be considered only 16 character long. So... which length would it be, according to your requirements, 16 or 18?

Comment: The string should never be shorter than the length of 'PLX000000000PQ50000'. After that it doesn't matter.

Comment: But that's 19 characters long... not 18

Comment: @FrancescoB. you're right I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to @Zenoo's answer, if you want to take into account `%20` as a single occurrence, you can use the following expression:

```
[pP]([a-zA-Z0-9 +-]|(%20)){14,}0000
```

where you basically add to the possible character list `%20` as a single occurrence.

[Here is the live demo](https://regex101.com/r/peJTjl/1), **which you can use to test all the examples you want** (I already included those you provided), with all the technical explanations needed, which I am copying below:

- pP matches a single character in the list pP (case sensitive)
- 1st Capturing Group ([a-zA-Z0-9 +-]|(%20)){14,} {14,} Quantifier —
  Matches between 13 and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
  giving back as needed (greedy)
- 1st Alternative [a-zA-Z0-9 +-] Match a single character present in
  the list below [a-zA-Z0-9 +-] a-z a single character in the range
  between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
- A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index
  90) (case sensitive) 0-9 a single character in the range between 0
  (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- +- matches a single character in the list  +- (case sensitive)
- 2nd Alternative (%20) 2nd Capturing Group (%20) %20 matches the
  characters %20 literally (case sensitive)
- 0000 matches the characters
  0000 literally (case sensitive)

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it doesn't allow the '%' to be present without a following '20'

Comment: @Dzienny we are still trying to figure out whether that's ok or not, i.e. complying with the requirements. In my opinion it might be this way, since if %20 is just an encoding for blank, it should count as a single character.

Comment: @FrancescoB. Okay, I see now. By the way, you could use non capturing groups.

Comment: Can you update your answer to match the updated length of at least 19 characters?

Comment: Done. It just required to replace 13 with 14 to reflect the updated requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this RegEx : [`[pP][a-zA-Z0-9- +%]{13,}0000`](https://regex101.com/r/oqLQEq/1)

`[pP]` matches a single character in the list `pP` (case sensitive)

`{13,}` matches 13 or more iterations of `[a-zA-Z0-9- +%]`

- `a-z` a single character in the range between `a` (index 97) and `z` (index 122) (case sensitive)
- `A-Z` a single character in the range between `A` (index 65) and `Z` (index 90) (case sensitive)
- `0-9` a single character in the range between `0` (index 48) and `9` (index 57) (case sensitive)
- `- +%` matches a single character in the list `- +%` (case sensitive)

`0000` matches the characters `0000` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: This is a great answer, the only thing that's missing is that I don't want to have '%' as a single character or "%2" as a string. I only want to accept "%20" as a whole

Answer (score 2):

A regex can be used to precisely match the format:

```
^(?=.{14,}0000$)[pP][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:(?(1)\1|([- +]|%20)?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

- `(?=.{14,}0000$)` asserts a line which is >= 18 in length and ends with `0000`
- `(?(1)\1|([- +]|%20)?)` is an *if clause* which checks if delimiter is matched it should be used as the next delimiter

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/23MRPN/1)